# Transfer csv to elasticsearch from Python with document_id as csv field

Tags: python, elasticsearch

wanted to transfer following csv to elsticsearch

```
|hcode|hname|
|1|aaaa|
|2|bbbbb|
|3|ccccc|
|4|dddd|
|5|eeee|
|6|ffff|
```

and need to insert hcode field as document_id. getting below error

```
  File "C:\Users\Namali\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\base.py", line 181, in _raise_error
    status_code, error_message, additional_info

RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'failed to parse')"
```

use elasticseach version is 7.1.1 and python vervion is 3.7.6
Python code-----------------------------------------------------------------

```
import csv
import json

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

def csv_reader(file_obj, delimiter=','):
   reader_ = csv.reader(file_obj,delimiter=delimiter,quotechar='"')
   
   i = 1
   results = []
   for row in reader_:
    #try :
    #es.index(index='hb_hotel_raw', doc_type='hb_hotel_raw', id=row[0], 
                # body=json.dump([row for row in reader_], file_obj))
    es.index(index='test', doc_type='test', id=row[0],body=json.dumps(row))
    #except:
    #    print("error")
    i = i + 1
    results.append(row)
    print(row)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  with open("D:\\namali\\rez\\data_mapping\\test.csv") as f_obj:
    csv_reader(f_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, doc_type is omitted in the elasticsearch 7. Second, you need to pass a valid json to elasticsearch. I edited your code as below:

```
for row in reader_:
    _id = row[0].split("|")[1]
    text = row[0].split("|")[2]
    my_dict = {"hname" : text}
    es.index(index='test', id=_id, body=my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

<disclosure: I'm the developer of Eland and employed by Elastic>

If you're willing to load the CSV into a Pandas DataFrame you can use [Eland](https://github.com/elastic/eland) to create/append the tabular data to an Elasticsearch index with all data types resolved properly.

I would recommend reading [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and [`eland.pandas_to_eland()`](https://eland.readthedocs.io/en/7.7.0a1/reference/api/eland.pandas_to_eland.html#eland.pandas_to_eland) function documentation for ideas on how to accomplish this.